# How to connect a mono microphone to a stereo input (mini jack) without losing a channel?

Tags: microphone, connector, signal-routing, adapters

I record live music with a small "pocket" video camera (Kodak "Playtouch" Zi10).

The internal condenser mic is pretty lame. I tried one of the "SONY" (a knock-off, I'm sure) ECM-DS70P T-shaped plug-in mics, but the "figure 8" pattern of the mics does as good a job of picking up the (increasingly getting worse at shows) chatter in the audience as it does the stage sound - same with that internal (along with lousy dynamic range).

In search of a solution, I just purchased an older (late-'80s) Azden ECZ-660 "shotgun" one, with a "zoom" pattern option. While it has a clear (if somewhat bass-weak) sound, it's a mono mic - just one ring on the 3.5MM plug - so it's doing the (I think - not well-versed on the subject) "right to ground" thing, resulting in audio only on the left channel.

My question:

Is there any kind of inline adapter that will "bridge" the mono across both channels, so it's more listenable on headphones or other stereo set-ups?

I tried searches online, but such a thing either doesn't exist - or I can't word a search properly to find one.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Hi Don - welcome to Sound Design :-) I modified your question a little to make it easier to find for others. Please see my answer below and mark as "accepted" if it solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. According to [the manual](http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/155987/kodak-playtouch-zi10.html?page=29), the internal microphone is mono and the external microphone input is stereo.

**The easy - but possibly inoptimal - solution: A Jack Adapter**

You can try a mono to stereo adapter like this 3.5mm Stereo Male to 3.5mm Mono Female Adapter:
[image: C2G 40634 3.5mm Stereo Male to 3.5mm Mono Female Adapter]

I found one [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000O7AW98), but you can probably find them elsewhere. What is important is that you ensure it is a mono to stereo adapter.

Now this solution may not give the optimal results in regard to impedance and channel preamp isolation. This could result in a weaker sound, in particular regarding the low end.

**The optimal solution: A Microphone Splitter**

To get around issues with impedance and preamp isolation, it would be more optimal to use a split box. However new challenges will emerge with the equipment you mention: the connectors! Now you need to convert mini jack to XLR ;-)

[image: Whirlwind IMP SPLITTER-1X3]

I think you should give the simple jack adapter a try before exploring the split box route. It is way cheaper and less complex.